# Provide example parameter in a Siri Tip View

Tags: swift, swiftui, appintents, app-shortcut

I am implementing iOS16 App Shortcuts. I am using `SiriTipView` to show users the possibilities.

My `AddItem` intent has a parameter for which `Box` entity to add the `Item` to. The shortcut will prompt for this.

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct MyShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider { 
    @AppShortcutsBuilder static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {  
        AppShortcut(intent: AddItem(), phrases: [
            "Add new item to \(\.$box) in \(.applicationName)",
            "Add new item in \(.applicationName)",
        ],
            shortTitle: "Add New Item",
            systemImageName: "pills"
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to add an example `Box` (from the user's existing data, like I do for the disambiguation) to the `SiriTipView`.

Currently, the tip view does not fill in the entity placeholder:

`"Add new item to ${box} in <My App Name>"`

The tip view is defined like this.

`SiriTipView(intent: AddItem())`

I realise I could just change the topmost phrase and have it use the phrase without the parameter, but I think it would be useful to the user to see that they can speak the box parameter.

I tried initialising the tip view with an `IntentParameter` like this:

`SiriTipView(intent: AddItem(box: IntentParameter<BoxAppEntity>))`

But I could not figure out how to just give it an example box entity. I guess I need to know how to initialise an IntentParameter with a concrete entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that with many of the `IntentParameter` initialisers, the name of my concrete entity was being ignored, or there were compile time errors.

In the end, I had to set the `wrappedValue` like this.

```
func getIntentParameter() -> IntentParameter<BoxAppEntity?> {
    let parameter = IntentParameter<BoxAppEntity?>(title: "Example Parameter")
    parameter.wrappedValue = BoxAppEntity(id: "boxID", displayString: "Box Name")
    return parameter
}
```

Then I used this in the `SiriTipView`:

```
SiriTipView(intent: AddItem(box: getIntentParameter()))
```

In the `getIntentParameter` method I can simply set the `displayString` based on some arbitrary user data.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me, too! But I wonder, what is the "title" for? Do I need to localize it? It doesn't seem to be shown to the user anywhere, right?

Comment: @Jeehut I wondered this too. I didn’t localise it, and I haven’t seen it surface anywhere in iOS.